# How many moles of aspartame are present in 4.00mg of aspartame? (3 sig figs)

Tags: mole

*This is a part of my online chemistry homework (mastering chemistry)*

I know how to do it but when I enter $\pu{1.36E-5}$ into the program, it says that it's incorrect and that the correct answer does not depend on $\times10$. I'm not sure what it wants from me. The answer should be given in moles with $3$ sig figs.

Comment: What if you put in 0.0000136? The way you ask your question gives very limited scope to understand what is happening. What program are you using? What is the exact answer given from the program? Other information would be helpful.

Comment: I will add that as an answer and hopefully you will accept it, and close off the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting in 0.0000136. Remember that zeroes between the decimal point and the last numbers do not contribute to significant figures. Good luck.